# Name of a certain economic fallacy

Tags: reference-request

I remember seeing a fallacy mentioned concerning the different valuations you put on something just because you own it. I would like a link to the discussion of that fallacy. Thanks.

Comment: This seems rather broad.  [Sunk cost fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_cost)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [endowment effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endowment_effect) is the hypothesis that people ascribe more value to things merely because they own them.